# collection not getting populated - backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a fetch method in my collection class which properly logs a response in the console from the url i have specified. The response from the url looks like this in the console,

```
[
Object
Desc: "Desc of Qn0"
Qno: 0
__proto__: Object
, 
Object
Desc: "Desc of Qn1"
Qno: 1
__proto__: Object
, 
Object
Desc: "Desc of Qn2"
Qno: 2
__proto__: Object
, 
Object
Desc: "Desc of Qn3"
Qno: 3
__proto__: Object
, 
Object
Desc: "Desc of Qn4"
Qno: 4
__proto__: Object
]
```

The fetch method is as follows,

```
app.collections.CollectionItems.fetch({

                success: function (collection,response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    //console.log(response[0].Desc);
                    //app.collections.CollectionItems.add(response);
                    console.log(app.collections.CollectionItems.length);
                    app.views.app = new app.views.masterView({collection: app.collections.CollectionItems});
                }
            });
```

Now when I try to log the length of the collection, it says zero. And to confirm my doubt, I tried to loop through the models in the collection (inside the render method of the view)which showed me that the collection had no models. What more than fetch() should i do to populate the collection ?

Comment: Copy/pasting logs the way you did isn't ideal, as we can't see the full contents of what came back.  Could you please try doing a `console.log(JSON.stringify(arguments));` (instead of `console.log(response);`) and putting that output in to the answer instead?

Comment: What do you mean by arguments .. U mean the response object that I am loggin already ?

Comment: The thing you logged says `Object`, and it's hard to tell if we're seeing the full depth of that object.  I'm looking for the contents of that object spelled out explicitly; in other words something like `{foo: 'bar'}`.  The `JSON.stringify` line I suggested will log exactly that.

Comment: [{"Qno":0,"Desc":"Desc of Qn0"},{"Qno":1,"Desc":"Desc of Qn1"},{"Qno":2,"Desc":"Desc of Qn2"},{"Qno":3,"Desc":"Desc of Qn3"},{"Qno":4,"Desc":"Desc of Qn4"}]                                         This is the result

Comment: Ok, I appreciate that you're trying not to provide excess information, and I guess I should have been more specific previously, but ... please do run the line of code I provided, not a modified version of it.  Then, since it may be too long for a comment, please edit your answer and add it.  This will not only show the response, but also the state of the collection at that moment in time (because the collection will be the first argument).

Comment: Will do that @machineghost